# Sitecore website only pointing to French Version

Tags: sitecore

I created a multilingual website with ( English and french). Both the version are working fine in my Dev environment. but after creating the packages and installed on Staging , my website only points to french version.

any help...

Comment: Could you give us more information on what is exactly happening?

Comment: Are you using language versions on the same tree of items or are do you have a separate subtree for each language?  Does the content tree appear as expected on the staging site when viewed in the Sitecore client?  Are you using one of the language fallback modules?  Can you show us the sites section of your web.config (after include files have been merged)?

Comment: Hi,
can you send us <sites> section definition from your Staging Section. 
Do you see on content editor both version? If not please check /sitecore/system/Languages if ID of english and french items are same on staging and dev servers.

Comment: can you try with sc_lang={french locale} in the query string to check the language item exits? Also make sure the language is created in staging before package installation.

Comment: @BenGolden , I am using same tree of items. Content tree appears same when viewed in sitecore client. No fallback is being used yet.     <site name="yyy" hostName="www.yy.com"  virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/yyy" language="en"  database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>
      <site name="yyy_fr" hostName="fr.yy.com"  virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/yyy" language="fr" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>

Comment: @sitecoreclimber i posted <sites> section above. Both version are there in staging , when i preview them . But afte publishing only french version is coming. Only language ID of English is same on Dev and staging but french and spanish had diff ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the language on your staging environment. Sitecore will install items with undefined languages just fine, but they won't work properly until the language is installed and registered.

Can be done from Sitecore Control Panel, Globalization options as I recall.

Comment: Yes it worked after installing the languages on staging environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the relevant sections of your web.config (and config include) files are the same in both environments (e.g. check `<sites>` section).
2. Ensure you have published **both languages** in your staging environment?